# Regex stack expressions to split long words into chunks

Tags: javascript, regex

I tried to stack two regex expressions, but without any luck.

In my case I need to find all words with length 50 and larger

```
\w{50,}
```

and now I need to split only those matches in chunks by 10 characters.

```
.{1,10}
```

I was unable to apply second expression to the first expression matches.
Do you've any ideas?

Thanks!!!

Comment: What language or regex tool are you using?

Comment: Finally I need this expression in Javascript

Comment: Javascript [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) can take a function as replacement. Just pass the `\w{50,}` to a function that splits after every ten.

Comment: Like [this demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##pU4xDsMgDNx5hTdAopAMnaL@pAulJCVKcGRIOkR5O6Xq0q1DJd/ZJ92dPNrNJkdhyaeId1/KZglSJrgA7xHxZqkO0V83fAn4lXgb6uYdY58/Kmvyy2SdF@b63M@NOoyCfo0uB4xilrAzAPJ5pQiznm12D2H03qq2Ocwg9YghCg5cduyoYA5jwsnrCQdR22VXygs).

Comment: @bobblebubble that would seem worthy of an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) can take a function as replacement.

```
str = str.replace(/\w{50,}/, function(m) {
  return m.match(/.{1,10}/g).join(' ');
});
```

[See this demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##pU4xDsMgDNx5hTdAopAMnaL@pAulJCVKcGRIOkR5O6Xq0q1DJd/ZJ92dPNrNJkdhyaeId1/KZglSJrgA7xHxZqkO0V83fAn4lXgb6uYdY58/Kmvyy2SdF@b63M@NOoyCfo0uB4xilrAzAPJ5pQiznm12D2H03qq2Ocwg9YghCg5cduyoYA5jwsnrCQdR22VXygs) - or a bit shorter one:

```
str = str.replace(/\w{50,}/, m => m.match(/.{1,10}/g).join(' '));
```

No idea if it's possible in JS with just one regex. In PCRE: [`(?:\G\B|\b(?=\w{50}))\w{10}\B\K`](https://regex101.com/r/5fg19E/1)